# CSS Image Location Adjustment

Tags: css

I am trying to place the COLLECTION image located on my [website](http://gamekrib.com/l3th_Gunslinger/) to the left to overhang and drop just above the text with CSS, but I am unable to figure out the placement. any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.plt_22 {
background: url(http://i1108.photobucket.com/albums/h412/l3th_gunslinger/Collection.png) no-repeat 0 0;
padding: 70px 0 0 0;
}
```

Comment: I had to tweak it a little which is no problem. Do you  or anyone know of a way to push it to the left to overlap the outer part of the column without it disappearing?

Comment: Hmm, remove the background image from .plt_22 and your code can become like this .plt{padding:70px 0 0 0; position:relative;} .plt:before {content: "\0020"; position:absolute; width:200px /*adjust this*/; height:100px /* adjust this */; background: url(http://i1108.photobucket.com/albums/h412/l3th_gunslinger/Collection.png) no-repeat 0 0; top:0; left: -100px /* adjust this */;}

Comment: It removed everything from the Profile

Comment: Well, I gave you the hint... you should be able to play around. Maybe there is a typo on my latest comment?

Comment: Ill find it, Thank you for your help